# Is there any way to take multiple column as training dataset in TFIDF Algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, recommendation-engine, tfidfvectorizer

I have been trying TF_IDF recommendation algorithm with one column as Input and One column as output was successfully developed.
Now, I want to take four-column as the Training dataset but it is not working Any Idea?

Here is my dataset

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IRi404gWcWKCeLRGFf6ung9lAHPSbnFHvJNwyfCFJpM/edit?usp=sharing

code I have been try

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

data = pd.read_csv("ADL Dataset V1.csv", sep=",")

reactants = data["Name"]["Smile Canonical"]["Mobile phase"]["Chomatrographic mode"]
reactans = reactants.tolist()
targets = data["Column"].tolist()

# TFIDF vector representation
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(targets)
# Taking first record as test sample X[0:1]
cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(X[0:1], X).flatten()

# Extract top 5 similarity records
similarity = cosine_similarities.argsort()[:-5:-1]
for sim in similarity:
    print(reactants[sim])
```

I want to pass the above 4 columns as a training dataset and make recommendations. Can anybody help me out?